# Confusion in calculation

Tags: c

This program calculates the discount. If I change the variable priceperitem to int and do the necessary changes in the code(format specifiers etc.) , the statement that calculates the discount gives me different answer altogether.Can anybody explain the logic behind this.I have tried hard but could not understand what's wrong?? .. can it be related to Associativity of Operators .. or is it just the division thing ... ???

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int quantity;
    float priceperitem,expense,discount;

    printf("Price Per Item =");
    scanf("%f",&priceperitem);

    printf("How much quantity do you want =");
    scanf("%d",&quantity);

    if(quantity>1000)
    {
        discount=quantity*priceperitem*10/100;
        printf("The discount is %f\n",discount);
        expense=quantity*priceperitem - discount;
        printf("The discounted price is %f",expense);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the given input and what it's outputting?

Comment: You are looking at [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_integers)

Comment: `10/100` evaluates to `0`

Comment: **Copy and paste** code that doesn't work, together with the problematic input. No one knows what you deem "necessary changes".

Comment: @n.m. - seems like you had a problem understanding my question when everyone is clear and have put their constructive comments ...

Comment: You have presented a low-quality question, that some people nevertheless found answerable.  I did not try to understand it, merely pointed out a way to improve it. Good luck.

Comment: @n.m. - Seeing your past comments , not in once you have "pointed out a way to improve it" ... looks like you wrote it in INVISIBLE INK which only you can decipher .. Thank you for the help anyways ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `priceperitem` to `int` will give different result due to integer division.

Change `discount=quantity*priceperitem*10/100;`

To `discount=quantity*priceperitem*10/100f;`

Comment: Or just change `10/100` to `0.1`.

Comment: Ok , what if i would have replaced 10/100 by 0.1 and changed priceperitem to int ??? ... it still shows me the wrong answer ... by concept , in an expression evaluation , if a real value is present then all the integer values must be changed to real...

Answer (score 0):

If it changes from and int to a float it won't take into account decimal places, perhaps this is your change in answer due to integer division change

Comment: Ok , what if i would have replaced 10/100 by 0.1 and changed priceperitem to int ??? ... it still shows me the wrong answer ... by concept , in an expression evaluation , if a real value is present then all the integer values must be changed to real...